# How do I remind my boss that my raise still has not been applied?

Tags: professionalism, salary, raise, payroll

Payroll is a week late with my raise. On the day my raise was supposed to be applied I received my normal pay. I notified my boss via slack and he said he would remind payroll.

At the end of the week I asked for updates but the message was ignored.

Should I just wait for my next pay cycle (fortnightly) or should I bring it up again?

Comment: Do you not have contact information for your company's payroll or HR team? Also be sure to ask that they include the amount(s) underpaid in your next pay cycle once this issue is resolved.

Comment: I do, I think I will go directly to payroll if it is not reflected in my next pay, including backpay.

Comment: Just to make sure, but you do have it in writing that you were supposed to get a raise? It is not just a raise the manager said you would get in a face-to-face conversation? In the latter case this becomes a totally different question.

Comment: I do have it in writing yes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it were me I would wait until the next pay cycle. If it still isn't reflected in your pay then I would simultaneously address it with your boss and with your HR department.

Make sure that your raise is retroactive to the date it was supposed to be reflected in your pay.

Comment: Thank you, this feels appropriate to me as well. I wasn't quite sure but I am happy to wait for the next pay cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Same here last month with my raise after probation, written in my contract. But instead of contacting my boss I went straight to HR next time I was in office.

There, I did not talk about an "error". I simply showed her my contract and asked as innocently as possible where I'd have to go to get the promised raise. I asked if I'd have to have a one-on-one-talk to my boss for reviewing my probation period or if I was right in talking directly to HR.

HR told me I was completely right to ask her instead of the boss. It turned out she had just mixed up my starting date, thinking the raise was due one month later and she'll correct it in hindsight. We were both happy the boss wasn't involved as it was a mistake she made, which he doesn't even need to know.